# What is the expected runtime of a while loop that relies on a coin flip?

Tags: java, random, while-loop, runtime, computer-science

I've been working on a SkipList implementation in Java for my CS2 class, and after analyzing the runtime of all my methods (for fun), I had a problem identifying the average runtime of the following:

```
// Returns 1 with 50% probability, 2 with 25% probability,
// 3 with 12.5% probability, and so on, without exceeding maxHeight
private static int generateRandomHeight(int maxHeight)
{
    int height = 1;
    // At most O(maxHeight) which is O(log(n))
    // Best case is O(1) and on average O(log(log(n)))??
    while (--maxHeight > 0 && Math.random() < .5)
            height++;

    return height;
}
```

I know that the best runtime is O(1) and the worst runtime is O(h), which is guaranteed to be O(log(n)), since h = ⌈log₂(n)⌉ *(ceiling of log base two of n)*.

Question is, **what is the average expected runtime of this function**?

At first glance, I assumed that it is expected to be O(log(log(n))). I brought this question to my TAs and after discussing with them, we are leaning on an average runtime of O(1), since it's most likely that we iterate only once or not at all (e.g 50%).

Comment: I normally read O(1) as constant which isn't quite true here. It is bounded by maxHeight, so worst case is O(n) - best case O(1). You probably branch off into statistical theory => Random < 0.5 doesn't mean every second number will be > 0.5, so assuming 0 or 1 loop iterations isn't quite right. I guess you need to decide if you want worst case or "average" case.

Comment: Talking about the average case. And it's O(1) since it does not rely on n or h. Regardless of the size of those, it is most likely that it will iterate once or none. There's a 50% for no iterations, 25% for one, 12.5% for two, and so on. Even if n is a huge size, it's fairly unreasonable to have more than let's say 8 iterations. That's why the average case is O(1)

Comment: I agree, in the real world your right, but I'm, sure there will be a mathematician reading this yelling obscenities at their screen ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Calculating complexity is often complicated when you have probability. But you were right, it was O(1), but not exactly O(1). O(1) is defined as constant, which means that no matter what you input, the run time would be the same. However, in your case, `Math.random()` isn't predictable. But, nevertheless, its's still O(1) because the run-time stays relatively constant as `n` increases. I made a test to see the number of times the loop iterates, and my results were really similar.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int n = 0; n < 100; n ++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                    l.add(j);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(average(l));
        l.clear();
    }


}

private static double average(List<Integer> l) {
    double sum = 0;

    for(int i : l) {
        sum += i;
    }

    return sum / l.size();
}
```

Here are a few results. As you can see, they hover around 1.

```
1.011
0.986
1.046
0.991
0.953
0.984
1.017
0.973
```